# Center 2 DIVs: Do I need to put them in a container DIV?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'd like my 2 DIVs to be horizontally centered (and next to each other at the same level). I know that I can achieve that by wrapping these 2 DIVs into a "container" DIV but was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this?
Thanks

```
#bottom-left {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;;
    background: #5421c2;
}

#bottom-right {
    float: right;
    width: 480px;;
    background: #2ec4a6;

}
```

Comment: And they are not horizontal aligned now?

Comment: Stick a wrapper div around them, the HTML police won't come after you and it's (no longer?) looked at as bad practice like it was a few years ago when the competition was on to get the lowest markup to content ratio possible.

Comment: Further, to make yourself feel better about using a wrapper, google "CSS grid systems" and take a look at some of their markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to achieve the above

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKCAS/) (You can resize the fiddle window and see)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKCAS/1/) (Dimensions changed for demonstration purposes)

Explanation: We are using a `wrapper` element here set to `margin: auto;` which will center your element horizontally, `div` which will wrap your floating elements, and than we assign the total width, that is left floated div + right floated div, and than as the `.wrap` contains floating elements, we use `.clear` to clear the floats. You can also use `overflow: hidden;` or `clearfix hacks` instead of the properties am using in class `.clear`

```
.wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #000;
}

#bottom-left {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;;
    background: #5421c2;
    height: 300px;
}

#bottom-right {
    float: right;
    width: 480px;;
    background: #2ec4a6;
    height: 300px;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Alien. So no way to achieve this without wrapping them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this isn't really generally possible with fixed width items without a container, however you may be able to accomplish this with calc something like this.

```
margin: 0 calc(50% - 480px);
```

The calc would also be different for each container

I can't test this out, it may not work but I would say that calc is your only  chance